# How can we run matlab function code in my android application?

Tags: android, matlab, android-studio

I have a function of Matlab, which is performing a specific task. The parameter which is passed to this function is extracted in the android application. Now I want to run this function inside my android application by passing the extracted parameters. Can you please suggest how to do this or if any workaround is available or not?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this I can think of would be to use the Matlab [CodeGen](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html) toolbox to create C++ code for your function.

You could then use this code within your android project.

If you've got Simulink, potentially you could do some stuff with the [Android Support Package](https://au.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/android/)

Personally, I think you're better off using NumPy and Python if you're targeting an Android Environment.